# Is it possible to test for IE in javascript without browser sniffing and conditional comments?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I'm curious to know if it's possible to switch between Javascript `insertRule` and `addRule` methods in Javascript without using browser sniffing/conditional comments to assign `addRule` to IE.

In CSS, I can use properties that aren't supported on specific devices (IE ::pseudo-selector for example) to write rules for specific browsers. Is there a similar trick in Javascript?

Thanks for some insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sheet.addRule) { 
    sheet.addRule(...);
}
else
{
    sheet.insertRule(...);
}
```

Comment: ok. finally got around to doing this. what is sheet supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Use [feature detection](https://www.google.com/search?q=JavaScript+feature+detection) instead:

```
var abstractedInsertOfRule = function (rule, stylesheet){
    //if (object) is a quick way to test if the object is defined
    //in browsers that do not implement "insertRule",
    //if (insertRule) returns "falsy"
    if (insertRule) {
        insertRule(rule, stylesheet);
    } else if (addRule) {
        addRule(rule, stylesheet);
    } else {
        //call other rule insertion methods here
    }
};
```